# Is it possible to connect Oracle with ArcGIS for doing spatial query?

Tags: oracle, gis, geospatial, spatial, arcgis

Is it possible to connect Oracle with ArcGIS for doing spatial query?

Answer (score 1):

Google suggests you use [ArcSDE](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_the_Oracle_Spatial_geometry_type), or possible [Direct Connect](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc03/p0820.pdf)